# How can I semantically represent groups of table cells?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I have a table which looks like this:

[image]

I'm looking for a semantically meaningful representation for it. I am **NOT** looking to get the same visualization.

What I struggle with are those two groups "Other operating charges" and "Financial income and expenses". How can I group elements within HTML?

### My best try

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Profit and Loss Account</th>
            <th>01.01.-31.12.2018</th>
            <th>01.01.-31.12.2017</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Net Turnover</strong></td>
            <td>1234567.89</td>
            <td>12456.78</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other operating charges</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp; Management fee</td>
            <td>-12345.56</td>
            <td>-54321.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp; Other operating charges</td>
            <td>-1234.50</td>
            <td>-1234.12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>1220987.73</td>
            <td>-43098.34</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Operating Profit (Loss)</strong></td>
            <td>5 700 000,00</td>
            <td>2 100 000,00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Financial income and expenses</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp; Reduction in value of investments held as non-current assets</td>
            <td>-3000000.00</td>
            <td>-400000.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp; Other financial income and expenses</td>
            <td>-12 000,00</td>
            <td>-18 000,00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>-3012000.00</td>
            <td>-418000.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Profit (loss) for the period</strong></td>
            <td><strong>2 688 000,00</strong></td>
            <td><strong>1 682 000,00</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: `<colgroup>`, `role="rowgroup"`?

Comment: These examples may be helpful: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/multi-level/

Comment: @Sean and Stanislav: Wow, I didn't even know those exist! Thank you! I think you could make both of those comments answers. I would upvote both :-)